# pip install opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\users\imranliaqat\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Lib\site-packages\cv2\cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Seems pretty straight-forward of a problem; WinError 5 is always a permission problem.  You will have to solve the problem of why you can't write to your appdata directory.  Perhaps you need to install as Administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type the command you want execute with the user permission, if you don't want to change the permission:

`pip3 install opencv-contrib-python --user`

Or just change the access permission, where the particular package is going to install.

In your case **windows10**:

- goto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39" (wherever your python is installed.)
- right click on Python39 folder and click on properties
- goto Security tab and allow full control by clicking edit button.
- again open new cmd terminal and try to install the package again.

Otherwise open `command prompt` with Run as administrator and do the same thing.

Comment: "C:\Program Files(X86)\Python39" has nothing to do with it.  Do not allow full control of this directory!  The problem is in the user's appdata or somewhere below that.  Full Control is a major security issue.

Answer (score 1):

On windows10 python3.8, I had this permission problem even when installing as Administrator.
The problem was due to the McAfee so-called protection package.
I deinstalled it and then pip installs worked OK.